# UISearchController. search controller doesn't resize after device rotated

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using UISearchController on my view to find items. Search bar resizes properly in inactive move.However, if you enable searching and rotate device from landscape to portrait and to landscape mode again it won't fit to view.On my view I use navigation item which can be toggled in portrait mode.
I tried to resize search bar view dynamically, it resized but position of search bar left the same. 
Initialization of search controller:

```
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = false
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: tableCellName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: tableCellName)
```

1.[image: There is navigation view and main view with search bar]

2.Let's enable searching and rotate device to portrait and landscape again.
[image: There is an issue here.]

3. It seems that search bar width includes width of navigation view. However,when it's inactive it fits to entire view.
   [image]

Comment: Are you use autolayout ?

Comment: Yes,thanks for the important remark. We use constraints for main view.

Comment: did you set constraint for searchbar ?

Comment: No,I didn't. I set search bar as a header of tableView. I suppose constraints are applied for search bar autimatically. Like I said, resize issue appears only when search bar is enabled.

Comment: I am not sure how you setup your searcherController?. you could run some IF condition when searchController is active to fit to width...my test project runs ok...post your searchController code...

Comment: Re:initialization.  I made changes in description.

Comment: Regarding "IF condition when searchController is active to fit to width". It seems the problem that search bar recalculates width in portrait mode the follow way "navigation.view.width"+"table view.width". On the other hand it doesn't calculate when search bar is inactive. Even more,table resize properly.

Comment: @AndreyDG Do you got any solution I am facing same issue for search bar not resizing when orientation changed.